# Watson conversation list entity value

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation

In Watson Conversation when I create a dialog, can I list the values of my Entity?? for sample I have one entity fruits (apple, orange, and etc) so in one of my responses can I list the content of @fruits??

tks

Answer (score 1):

For access intents and entities, first, your *user* need to request something for calling this objects... And in this case, your application will access:

- Name of entity (@fruits);
- The value of your entity typed from your user

Your app will show Fruit:orange if you user type orange, and Watson will recognize the entity and the value and save inside `entities.fruit[0]`, not all values from your entity inside @fruits, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43685643/ibm-watson-conversation-find-the-same-entity-several-times-in-the-same-input/43697652#43697652).

Access entity: IBM Official [Documentation](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/conversation/expression-language.html#accessing-entities).

*Anyway*: I think you want all values. Right?

I guess that best form is using `context` variables to save all "fruits" and show like:

**For this Dialog runtime context:**

```
{
  "context": {
    "toppings_array": ["orange", "apple"]
  }
}
```

**Update:**

```
{
  "context": {
    "toppings_array": "<? $toppings_array.append('banana', 'melon') ?>"
  }
}
```

**Result:**

```
{
  "context": {
    "toppings_array": ["orange", "apple", "banana", "melon"]
  }
}
```

**Show for the user:**

```
{
  "output": {
    "text": "This is the array: <? $toppings_array.join(', ') ?>"
  }
}
```

**All JSON Example:**

```
{
  "context": {
    "fruits": [
      "lemon",
      "orange",
      "apple"
    ]
  },
  "output": {
    "text": {
      "values": [
        "This is the array: <? $fruits.join(', ') ?>"
      ],
      "selection_policy": "sequential"
    }
  }
}
```

**Result:**

```
This is the array: lemon, orange, apple
```

[image]

See the official example from [Official](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIVzB.jpg) Documentation.

Comment: buw how I show this to my user? I know how create and update one context var, but how I list all values of an array to my user.